# Cannot start AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have seen soo many questions and answers about this but cannot get answer suitable for me . I cannot create or start any device

[image: THere is a caution sign : A repairable virtual device . which is not seen commonly]

[image: I cannot click on OK button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download and install an image suitable for that API level. Notice that the "CPU/ABI" field is greyed out. That's telling exactly what you need to do. Simply open the SDK Manager, look for your target API Level group, expand it and you should see a couple of system images you can download and install for that API Level...see screenshot below, I have highlighted what the system image would look like in the SDK Manager...

[image]

After downloading and installing it you will be able to select a system image from the AVD Manager for that API Level and create a virtual device

Comment: Hey, thanks for the sharing, bro.

Answer (score 2):

The part that you highlighted in the first picture is just the caption for the dialog. They're there just to tell you what a red cross and a yellow warning sign before the name of an AVD mean.

The second picture says that you can't create an AVD because you have "No system images installed for this target". To fix that, you need to launch the Android package manager and install at least one system image for Android 4.4W.