# ERROR IN AVD //ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android-studio

Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD

Can anybody help out please!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332181/cannot-start-avd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332181/cannot-start-avd)